# How can I call a created object as a function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class `Notify`, for example:

```
class Notify {
    success(text) {
        // TODO
    }

    error(text) {
        // Todo
    }
}

export default new Notify();
```

When I'm using I call directly to methods in this class like `Notify.success()`, So, now I want to try a new way to call it like `Notify('my title', 'success')`. In PHP I know it's `__invoke` method, but in JS I don't know how to use it likes that. Can I do that in `class`? Or I have to use 'normally' functions.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no analogue of `__invoke` in JavaScript. You can make a function and then attach properties to is so that it can be used as an object too.

```js
function notifyConstructor() {
  // Make the function
  const notify = (text, type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'success': return notify.success(text);
      case 'error': return notify.error(text);
      default: throw TypeError(`Unknown type "${type}"`);
    }
  };

  // Attach public properties and methods to the function
  notify.success = text => {
    // TODO
  };
  notify.error = text => {
    // Todo
  };

  return notify;
}

const notify = notifyConstructor();  // Make a Notify instance
notify('my title', 'success');       // Call the instance
notify.success('my title');          // Call an instance method
```

Comment: So wonderful if `class` of JS includes `__invoke` method. So, thank you for helping me. I converted the class to use the function like your code. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the functions using the context `this` as follows.

*Be careful if you call the function `invoke` by itself (Stackoverflow error).*

```js
class Notify {
  constructor() {
  }
  
  invoke(msg, fn) {
    if (this[fn]) {
      this[fn](msg);
    } else throw new Error("Illegal argument Error.");
  }
  
  success(text) {
    console.log('Success:', text);
  }

  error(text) {
    console.log('Error:', text);
  }
}

let notify = new Notify();
notify.invoke('my title', 'success');
notify.invoke('my title', 'error');
notify.invoke('my title', 'ele');
```

Or, directly over the instantiated object:

```js
class Notify {
  constructor() {
  }
  
  success(text) {
    console.log('Success:', text);
  }

  error(text) {
    console.log('Error:', text);
  }
}

let notify = new Notify();
notify['success']('my title');
notify['error']('my title');
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I integrated your 'invoke' function with @Finesse's code. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript object property access using a dot (`.`) is short hand notation for accessing  the property using array notation (`[]`). Short hand notation does, however, require the property name to conform to the syntax used for identifiers.

Assuming `Notify` is the name of the imported instance,

`Notify["success"]("my title"]`

is equivalent to

`Notify.success( "my title")`